# .NetStandard nuget package issues with .NETFramework

Tags: asp.net, jwt, nuget-package, .net-standard

I have 3 projects:

1. SDK in .NETStandard 2.0 and I installed
   `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (5.4.0)` nuget package.
2. ASP.NET Core API in .NETCore 2.1
3. ASP.NET API in .NETFramework 4.7.2

And referenced sdk in both apis, I don't have any problem in .NETCore api but I got an error in .NetFramework api:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

It's not suppose to support .NEtStandard in both .NETFramework and .NET core? What I missed?

Comment: The cause might be that you let your .NET Standard project use `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` as a reference, and NuGet resolves the .NET Standard 2.0 version of it. `https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/` indicates that it has .NET Framework specific assemblies, and should be added as a reference in your ASP.NET API project.

Comment: @LexLi You're right, I add `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>` in the csproj file. and solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended the comment above.

Many NuGet packages do contain different assemblies for different target platforms (netxx and netstandardxx for example), and those assemblies are not interchangeable.

Therefore, you hit an issue when the project structure is as below,

net472 project --depends-->netstandard20 project --depends on--> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (netstandard20)

Because in this way, net472 project consumes the netstandard20 copy of the NuGet package, which triggers the error.

There are several ways to resolve it, and your solution is just one of them, that modifying the netstandard20 project to be multi-targeting (netstandard20 and net461). This tells NuGet to serve the proper assembly to net472 project and everything starts to work then.